# lock sms using sms content provider [Edit sms content provider]

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am working on an sms app.By using sms content provider I got all the fields.

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null); 


 _id
thread_id
address
person
date
read   
status
type
subject
body
locked
```

I could able to do all basic operations using the above fields.Now I want to make a sms locked state. How can I do that?.From status field I am always getting -1.What that means.I checked with both inbox and outbox.Please help me friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Sms.CONTENT_URI= Uri.parse("content://sms");   
Mms.CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://mms");
private void lockMessage(MessageItem msgItem, boolean locked) {
        Uri uri;
        if ("sms".equals(msgItem.mType)) {
            uri = Sms.CONTENT_URI;
        } else {
            uri = Mms.CONTENT_URI;
        }
        final Uri lockUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, msgItem.mMsgId);

        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put("locked", locked ? 1 : 0);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getContentResolver().update(lockUri,
                        values, null, null);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Just reminder, everything above is not include in SDK so carefull in usage.